# Defining a ball in mathematics

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, mathematics

Which are appropriate phrases to define a ball?

1. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.
2. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$.
3. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ about $x$.
4. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ with the center at $x$.

Or, without $,

1. Let B be the open ball of radius r centered at x.
2. Let B be the open ball of radius r around x.
3. Let B be the open ball of radius r about x.
4. Let B be the open ball of radius r with the center at x.

**Remark** I mean a ball in an arbitrary metric space.

Comment: In a math text you wouldn't say "ball", you'd say "sphere". I'm not sure what you mean by an "open" ball.

Comment: @snailplane MathJax is a site-wide setting, and the community needs to justify it with examples of how it would be useful. I doubt it would be enabled for ELL.

Comment: @Jay [Open ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_%28mathematics%29) is a technical term for the space within a sphere but excluding the surface of the sphere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question of technical jargon, not general English.

Answer (score 1):

Since a **ball** is a three dimensional object, to define it you need to specify its *radius* and  its *center.*

Its center is a *vector* (also three dimensions).  You can show this using typography or words:

*Let B be the open ball of radius r centered at the vector x.*

Most authors would define a standard typography to indicate scalars and vectors and use that throughout their textbook.

Comment: I don't want to get into a different question, but I wouldn't say that a ball or sphere is centered at a "vector", but rather at a "point". "Let B be the sphere of radius r centered at the point p", or for a specific case, "Let B be the sphere of radius 3 centered at the point (4, 7, -2)".

Comment: @Jay I agree, especially if it is clear from the context that the *point* is in 3-D space.

Comment: Actually, I meant to ask about a ball in an arbitrary metric space.

Comment: @Sinusx Then see Jay's comments, you may want to add a phrase about the multi-dimensional nature of the center point if it is not obvious from the context.